# No more pattern data allowed after {*...} or ** pattern element

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have migrated my springboot from 2.4 to 3.1 and these are my dependencies in gradle file.

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.2.0'
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-websocket:6.1.4'
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:3.2.0')
```

and my security config file

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class JwtSecurityConfig {
@Autowired
  private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  private RequestFilter requestFilter;

@Autowired
  private JwtEntryPoint jwtEntryPoint;

 @Autowired
  public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
  }

  @Bean
  public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailsService();
  }

@Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()).authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .requestMatchers("/student/{studentId}/**").permitAll()
    .requestMatchers("/{userId}/websocket/**").permitAll()
             .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .exceptionHandling(exp -> exp.authenticationEntryPoint(jwtEntryPoint))
        .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .addFilterBefore(requestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

i have simple controller ,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class StudentController {

@Autowired
private StudentRepository repository;

@GetMapping(value = "/{studentId}/get")
  public ResponseEntity<?> getStudent(@PathVariable String studentId) {
    return reposity.findById(studentId);
  }
}
```

But when i hit the endpoint it is giving, No more pattern data allowed after {*...} or ** pattern element.

i added property but still facing this issue

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ANT_PATH_MATCHER`
```

any solution for this issue? thanks in advance for the help.

UPDATE:

error logs,

```
org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PatternParseException: No more pattern data allowed after {*...} or ** pattern element
    at org.springframework.web.util.pattern.InternalPathPatternParser.peekDoubleWildcard(InternalPathPatternParser.java:250) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.util.pattern.InternalPathPatternParser.parse(InternalPathPatternParser.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PathPatternParser.parse(PathPatternParser.java:129) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.PathPatternMatchableHandlerMapping.lambda$match$0(PathPatternMatchableHandlerMapping.java:64) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.PathPatternMatchableHandlerMapping.match(PathPatternMatchableHandlerMapping.java:62) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector$LookupPathMatchableHandlerMapping.match(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:542) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servlet.util.matcher.MvcRequestMatcher.matcher(MvcRequestMatcher.java:95) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.check(RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.java:79) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.check(RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.java:48) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.authorization.ObservationAuthorizationManager.check(ObservationAuthorizationManager.java:63) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:95) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at com.westernacher.legalbot.domain.authorization.JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtRequestFilter.java:33) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
```

endpoint - http://localhost:8080/student/123/get

Comment: What URL do you call? Show the full error message. Show your Sprin Security `DEBUG` logs.

Comment: @dur updated the question with error log. url is http://localhost:8080/student/123/get -GET

Comment: Did you try `.requestMatchers(antMatcher("/student/{studentId}/**")).permitAll()` instead of `.requestMatchers("/student/{studentId}/**").permitAll()`?

Comment: Yes I tried this approach but it is not working.

Comment: `@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurity() {
return web -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/student/{studentId}/**");
}`

Added this bean and started working. Thanks @dur for the help

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't comment yet (due to StackExchange policies), therefore I can't thank [@dur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5277820/dur) by commenting under the original question.
Their suggestion:

> Did you try `.requestMatchers(antMatcher("/student/{studentId}/**")).permitAll()`
>
> instead of `.requestMatchers("/student/{studentId}/**").permitAll()`?

solved gracefully my problem with this configuration, where I used `org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher` passing the original `String` matchers:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic(basicConfigurer -> basicConfigurer
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint()))
        .csrf(csrfConfigurer -> csrfConfigurer
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()))
        .authorizeHttpRequests(matcherRegistry -> matcherRegistry
                .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/index.html"),
                                 antMatcher("/perform_login"),
                                 antMatcher("/login"),
                                 antMatcher("/app/**"),
                                 antMatcher("/favicon.ico"),
                                 antMatcher("/**/*.png"),
                                 antMatcher("/**/*.jpg"),
                                 antMatcher("/**/*.css"),
                                 antMatcher("/**/*.js")).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .logout(logoutConfigurer -> logoutConfigurer
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login"));
    return http.build();
}
```

If I could comment, I'd ask [@dur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5277820/dur) to change their comment into a proper answer, because it deserves to be recognized as such.